# Can a java application manage triggers and UDFs in Derby database?

Tags: java, database, triggers, user-defined-functions, derby

Can we **manage** [UDFs](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/dev/ref/rrefcreatefunctionstatement.html), and [triggers](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/dev/ref/rrefsqlj43125.html) in **Derby** database from our own **Java** Application ?

By managing I mean :

1. checking if it exists;
2. adding;
3. removing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`executeUpdate()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeUpdate()) to execute the desired DDL, e.g. CREATE FUNCTION, DROP FUNCTION, CREATE TRIGGER, DROP TRIGGER, etc.